# Click trigger with pass X, Y coordinates value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When we are click in any HTML element we can get **X, Y coordinate** in our mouse.

Is it possible in jquery or javascript trigger click event with pass X, Y Coordinates value of HTML element and also pass element z-index value.
Only call **#block2** not call **#block1**.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#block1 div').on('click', function(e)
  {
    console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY));
    var X = e.pageX;
    var Y = e.pageY;
    $('#block1').css({'pointer-events':'none'});
    $('#block1 div').css({'pointer-events':'none'});
    var eobj = new jQuery.Event("click");
    obj.pageX = X;
    obj.pageY = Y;
    $('#time_slice').trigger(obj);
  });
});


$('#block2').on('click', function(e){
   console.log(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY));
   $('#block1').css({'pointer-events':'auto'});
   $('#block1 div').css({'pointer-events':'auto'});
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shivamanhar/5hn4mwp7/21/)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `MouseEvent` and set `clientX` and `clientY` values.

Then dispatch that event.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  console.log(`you clicked at ${event.x},${event.y}`);
});

const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'clientX' : 200, 
    'clientY' : 500
  });
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```